# GCM padding or not?

Tags: padding, gcm

In this question on StackOverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31248777/can-pkcs5padding-be-in-aes-gcm-mode it's said that GCM doesn't require a padding: why?

Comment: Poss dupe http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/41867/block-size-in-cbc-and-gcm

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**TL;DR: Padding is part of the specification of the mode and thus doesn't need to be done by the user of the primitive.**

---

Internally GCM really is CTR mode along with a polynomial hashing function applied on the ciphertext. CTR-mode doesn't need padding because you can just partly use the bits the last counter block generated and the polynomial hash *does* use  (zero-)padding.

For the details, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode#Mathematical_basis).